# Trying to get working time and current state of machine with KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Well, let's suppose that I have the following table:

```
let test = datatable (Timestamp: datetime, Id: string, Value: dynamic)
[
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:25), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:30), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:35), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:36), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:03), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:03), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:04), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:05), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:25), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:25), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:26), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:27), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:37), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:47), "machineA", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:57), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:59), "machineA", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:25), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:30), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:35), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:36), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:03), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:03), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:04), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:05), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:25), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:25), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:26), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:27), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:37), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:47), "machineB", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:57), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:59), "machineB", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:25), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:30), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:35), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:36), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:03), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:03), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:04), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:05), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:25), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:25), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:26), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:27), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:37), "machineC", "True",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:47), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:57), "machineC", "False",
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:59), "machineC", "False",
];
```

Then, let's suppose that on:

- Timestamp stores the time when the event was registered.
- Id is the machine to register.
- Value is the state, True is working False is stopped.

Then, let's suppose that events can be registered without toggling sense at all, there can be records in sequence with several True or False values in a row.

With this in mind then, we want to know the time a machine is working. For this, the logic is that we must check for the time difference between True and False (and not vice-versa, because this is the time the machine is stopped).

Then:

```
    | where Timestamp > ago(1d) and (Value == "True" or Value == "False")
    | extend val=tostring(Value)
        | order by Timestamp asc
        | where val <> prev(val)
        | where val == "True" and next(val) == "False"
        | extend tiempoCiclo=next(Timestamp)-Timestamp
        | where tiempoCiclo >= 30s and tiempoCiclo <= 5m
    );
workingTime
    | summarize arg_max(Timestamp, val), max(Timestamp), avg(tiempoCiclo) / 1s by Id
    | order by maquina desc
```

The problem here is that we cannot know the current state of the machine because we are filtering by Value first True then False, then the latest value (`arg_max` value) will be always True.

Comment: Please add the required results.

Comment: Any reason you're using dynamic instead of bool?

Comment: Using a data sample like this, where the metrics are almost identical for all Ids, is a very bad idea since it can easily lead you to wrong solution that seems correct.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz my production environment uses that type of data. Also, on my production data I have values like that which I cannot control so, that's the question conditions.

Comment: **(1)** You didn't add the required results yet **(2)** You do have control on the values of your sample data. See how for all 3 Ids the min duration is 00:00:10, the max duration is 00:00:22 etc.? That's a really bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
let test = datatable (Timestamp: datetime, Id: string, Value: bool)
[
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:25), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:30), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:35), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:39:36), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:03), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:03), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:04), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:05), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:25), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:25), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:26), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:27), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:37), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:47), "machineA", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:57), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:59), "machineA", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:25), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:30), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:35), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:40:36), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:03), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:03), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:04), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:05), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:25), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:25), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:26), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:27), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:37), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:47), "machineB", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:57), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:41:59), "machineB", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:25), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:30), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:35), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:42:36), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:03), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:03), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:04), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:05), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:25), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:25), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:26), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:27), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:37), "machineC", True,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:47), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:57), "machineC", False,
  datetime(2022-11-09 11:43:59), "machineC", False,
];
test
| partition hint.strategy=native by Id
  (
    order by Timestamp asc
    | where Value != prev(Value)
    | extend next_Timestamp = next(Timestamp)
    | where Value
    | extend duration = next_Timestamp - Timestamp
    | summarize min(duration), avg(duration), max(duration), sum(duration)
               ,1st_start = min(Timestamp)
               ,(max_Timestamp, last_action, last_action_timestamp)  = arg_max(Timestamp, isnull(next_Timestamp), coalesce(next_Timestamp, Timestamp))
    | project-away max_Timestamp           
    | extend Id
  )
```

| min_duration | avg_duration | max_duration | sum_duration | 1st_start | last_action | last_action_timestamp | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:10 | 00:00:14 | 00:00:22 | 00:00:42 | 2022-11-09T11:39:25Z | true | 2022-11-09T11:40:57Z | machineA |
| 00:00:10 | 00:00:14 | 00:00:22 | 00:00:42 | 2022-11-09T11:40:25Z | true | 2022-11-09T11:41:57Z | machineB |
| 00:00:10 | 00:00:14 | 00:00:22 | 00:00:42 | 2022-11-09T11:42:25Z | false | 2022-11-09T11:43:47Z | machineC |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WWXWvbMBSG7wP5D6e9ssEZ/uyIhy%202wWD3ZTdjBMU%20pCr%20CLKcNqM/flJDYkvpVvksgQTJet7z5lUOnBolSOwlFFAxqd7bGsG7543aY80%2017so1TKA71UOvRS83QXwg9UD5rDtutpfLn4uF3A56MVhHK%20iaBWuIYryZJ3HmR/AbcPKB97i59sA7sWAwb%20ZJCQwdp1vrO7fhe7mQmmYh8lMd1QmJTBz01bM1Q25hECDKHHHHwlQYkMOOaSUQhmhULb%20z0v64sYYbeTK2HWc0r6bDUVmSzi5IzIpgZmddnR9Qy4h0CBK3EYbuUKJDTnkkFIKZYRCRhs5MbGZ91c3xmgjV8au834IsdlGblBitoSTOyKTEpjZaSfXN%20QSAg2ixG20kSuU2JBDDimlUEaC1n%20Bfn1aLvR4uFy8wJ4JySXvWlCn5Ac1Ciq93bFomeQHhO1RTYi6jKc/ADpRodC7l2ESWF%20enr3A0wMKPI2RcFPAXuDBe1355xP4LLGtoFXfm1GieN0YB1T/DUFLoRqUUW27sMVWo7cz0w9NwwT/jdDw1jujKh122E2XDXueLhU2Lk9ak1cQ9XKjygg9Zmtd2/70rKekR48B1EzBrNTKxmIjLyKgZJnYbbSpCcn7dqhrz/zRymzZsRr7Eq0nwZiGf4l1L7pHLOWKPbEjGM4mnq3AT38D/w9wb/vyWwwAAA==)

Comment: Well, the unique thing I want to say is that the `where Value` should be `where Value == "True"` because Value for True and False are string literals. Also, is there any performance concerns I should take care of? I'd like to use materialized views for this, shall you provide an example with this?

Comment: Also, I'm a little new with Kusto, could you document the summarize pipe? If I understood correctly you expect that the next_Timestamp is null in order to get the previous and then the newest timestamp (as they are ordered ¿ascending?) Why ascending and not descending?

Comment: Materialized views have significant limitations for their KQL syntax, many of them are logical limitations. I doubt if MV is feasible for this use-case. Anyways, your original question was answered.

Comment: **(1)** A solution can be created based on ascending or descending order. It doesn't really matter.  **(2)** I don't expect *next_Timestamp* to be null, but I know that if it is null, then the row with the max *Timestamp* holds the last action (start) and there wasn't a following row with stop action (at this stage of the query I have only start actions enriched with data of the stop actions that followed them)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Then should  ask a new question for materialized view?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I doubt if it can be achieved using MV. A batch process might be more feasible.